# Optimum volt not returning on lead acid battery when load is put on the battery

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid, discharging

My Tractor battery (110ah) 12V when I put it on backup check, when the load is put on the battery of discharging 400watt bulb, the battery doesn't reach back to 12v after load, it stays around 11.80 to 11.90.

please tell

Comment: What’s the question exactly?

Comment: He wants to know if this is normal.   Yes, it is normal.   The voltage drops as you discharge the battery, even if you remove the load.

Comment: How far the battery voltage recovers depends (roughly) on the current the load takes, how long the load has been connected, and how far the battery was charged before the test. 11.9V is not abnormal; if it stays there for a longer time it will probably need charging, though.

Comment: 11.8 V it s approximately 10-15% of energy left. Going further to discharge may damage battery.

Comment: Q! How charged is the battery when you do this? - 100%, 50%, 20%, ... ? Q2 What is the maximum voltage the battery is at say 12 hours after charging and without having had a load applied? || 12V lead acid batteries should not be left below about 12.6 to 12.8 V for any period oof time to prevent damage from sulphation.